# Excel 2010 how do you save a graph as an image?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I can't find a way to save my graphs as images in Excel 2010. I don't see any option under File -> Save As

And theres no export to image either...

Does any one know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the clipboard: copy/paste the graph to paint or photoshop.

Comment: Ah so no built in functionality?

Comment: @wduk no... afaik there is no build in functionality... copy/paste is a handy workaround.

Comment: For a bonus, on the Home ribbon in the clipboard group, the Copy button has a drop-down option of "Copy as picture" where you can choose to copy as a bitmap image or a picture (ie editable as vectors depending on target application), and as shown on screen or printed (usually makes little difference).